# Bash command to recognize difference between variables

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed, regex

I am given from stdin 2 variables a name and a number given in any order. How can I identify them correctly in a bash script such that I can print them in a file in the same order(age, Name)

```
./a.sh Fred 18 
./a.sh 17 Barbie
```

output file

```
18 Fred
17 Barbie
```

I don't know how can I use sed command correctly or regex to do that please could you help?

Comment: Are names always one word, or could there be a space in the name (Firstname Lastname)?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to abuse the fact that digits come before letters in all major character encodings.
Simply split the string into multiple lines, sort the lines, then merge the lines back together into a single line.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort | xargs echo
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.sh Fred 18
18 Fred
$ ./a.sh 17 Barbie
17 Barbie
```

It even works for multi-word names, but then you should enclose the name in quotes, to prevent `sort` from changing the order of the words.

```
$ ./a.sh "Fred Astaire" 18
18 Fred Astaire
$ ./a.sh Fred Astaire 18
18 Astaire Fred
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"

[[ "$arg1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && echo "$arg1 $arg2" ||
  echo "$arg2 $arg1"
```

Comment: Did you mean `|| echo "$arg2 $arg1"`?

Comment: Within `[[...]]` we can also use the [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching): `[[ $arg1 == +([0-9]) ]]`

Comment: @Kulfy I did thank you.